# When to use 'componentDidUpdate' method?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote dozens of Reactjs files, but I never used the `componentDidUpdate` method.

Is there any typical example of when need to use this method?

I want a real-world example, not a simple demo.

Comment: https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html

Comment: A simple case when you wish to set initial state of component on load.

Comment: @Rajesh Can you explain it or give me a example? Thanks!

Comment: I think the most common use-case is when you have other libraries (jQuery, D3...) that work directly on the DOM, coupled together with React. In such scenarios, if the other library needs to perform DOM transformations, you should use componentDidUpdate to ensure React's shadow DOM has been flushed to the real DOM.

Comment: To elaborate on @Jorge's comment: I think the most common case would be to READ from the real DOM after React has updated. E.g. when you want to know the exact dimensions of DOM elements, or the position of DOM elements in the viewport. E.g. for animations or transitions you want react to manage. I would definitely advise against using jQuery for changing the DOM after react has rendered. Having react + another library change the same piece of DOM is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with you @wintvelt on the whole "don't use another library that alters the DOM", but sometimes I found myself without any other choice, jQuery, for one, has some great plugins that have still no equivalent in the React ecosystem, since the latter is still fairly young.

Comment: @wintvelt I agree with you. Thanks~

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A simple example would be an app that collects input data from the user and then uses Ajax to upload said data to a database. Here's a simplified example (haven't run it - may have syntax errors):

```js
export default class Task extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      age: "",
      country: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._commitAutoSave();
  }

  _changeName = (e) => {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  }

  _changeAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({age: e.target.value});
  }

  _changeCountry = (e) => {
    this.setState({country: e.target.value});
  }

  _commitAutoSave = () => {
    Ajax.postJSON('/someAPI/json/autosave', {
      name: this.state.name,
      age: this.state.age,
      country: this.state.country
    });
  }

  render() {
    let {name, age, country} = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this._changeName} />
        <input type="text" value={age} onChange={this._changeAge} />
        <input type="text" value={country} onChange={this._changeCountry} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

So whenever the component has a `state` change it will autosave the data. There are other ways to implement it too. The `componentDidUpdate` is particularly useful when an operation needs to happen **after** the DOM is updated and the update queue is emptied. It's probably most useful on complex `renders` and `state` or DOM changes or when you need something to be the *absolutely* last thing to be executed.

The example above is rather simple though, but probably proves the point. An improvement could be to limit the amount of times the autosave can execute (e.g max every 10 seconds) because right now it will run on every key-stroke.

I made a demo on this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kpnyges5/) as well to demonstrate.

---

For more info, refer to the [**official docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

> `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

Comment: I think `this.setState({...}, callback)`, the `callback` equal `_commitAutoSave`, what do you think? So, I think this case can use `componentDidUpdate` method, but not must, am i right?
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpnyges5/1/)

Comment: Yes, you could use a callback, however the problem gets trickier when/if there are multiple setStates that are run in succession.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, one case to use `componentDidUpdate` is to solve multiple setStates!  Any other ideas?

Comment: @novaline I see they use it in the react-sound component https://github.com/leoasis/react-sound/blob/master/src/index.js .. I'm not exactly sure why they're using it but I thought I'd share the link for you to take a look.

Comment: This is a good example, but it's missing a key recommendation from the React docs.

"This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed)."

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Similarly, one should wrap the call in conditional logic whenever calling `setState` in CDU.

Comment: @theUtherSide, true. I'll add the link to that section of the docs.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you might add a state value from props in constructor or componentDidMount, you might need to call setState when the props changed but the component has already mounted so componentDidMount will not execute and neither will constructor; in this particular case, you can use componentDidUpdate since the props have changed, you can call setState in componentDidUpdate with new props.

Answer (score 5):

This lifecycle method is invoked as soon as the updating happens. The most common use case for the componentDidUpdate() method is updating the DOM in response to prop or state changes.

You can call setState() in this lifecycle, but keep in mind that you will need to wrap it in a condition to check for state or prop changes from previous state. Incorrect usage of setState() can lead to an infinite loop.
Take a look at the example below that shows a typical usage example of this lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
 //Typical usage, don't forget to compare the props
 if (this.props.userName !== prevProps.userName) {
   this.fetchData(this.props.userName);
 }
}
```

Notice in the above example that we are comparing the current props to the previous props. This is to check if there has been a change in props from what it currently is. In this case, there won’t be a need to make the API call if the props did not change.

For more info, refer to the  [official docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: What to do in case of `this.fetchData is not a function`?

Comment: tomrlh it's a function call

Answer (score 4):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ 

    if (this.state.authToken==null&&prevProps.authToken==null) {
      AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken()
      .then(token => {
        if (token) {
          AccountKit.getCurrentAccount().then(account => {
            this.setState({
              authToken: token,
              loggedAccount: account
            });
          });
        } else {
          console.log("No user account logged");
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log("Failed to get current access token", e));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used `componentDidUpdate()` in highchart.

Here is a simple example of this component.

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
window.Highcharts = require('highcharts');

export default class Chartline extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chart: ''
    };
  }

  public componentDidUpdate() {
    // console.log(this.props.candidate, 'this.props.candidate')
    if (this.props.category) {
      const category = this.props.category ? this.props.category : {};
      console.log('category', category);
      window.Highcharts.chart('jobcontainer_' + category._id, {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }
        },
        chart: {
          defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
        },
        xAxis: {
          // categories: candidate.dateArr,
          categories: ['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3', 'Day4', 'Day5', 'Day6', 'Day7'],
          showEmpty: true
        },
        labels: {
          style: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '25px',
            fontFamily: 'SF UI Text'
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Low',
            color: '#9B260A',
            data: category.lowcount
          },
          {
            name: 'High',
            color: '#0E5AAB',
            data: category.highcount
          },
          {
            name: 'Average',
            color: '#12B499',
            data: category.averagecount
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  }
  public render() {
    const category = this.props.category ? this.props.category : {};
    console.log('render category', category);
    return <div id={'jobcontainer_' + category._id} style={{ maxWidth: '400px', height: '180px' }} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When something in the state has changed and you need to call a side effect (like a request to api - get, put, post, delete). So you need to call `componentDidUpdate()` because `componentDidMount()` is already called.

After calling side effect in componentDidUpdate(), you can set the state to new value based on the response data in the `then((response) => this.setState({newValue: "here"}))`. 
Please make sure that you need to check `prevProps` or `prevState` to avoid infinite loop because when setting state to a new value, the componentDidUpdate() will call again.

There are 2 places to call a side effect for best practice - componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

@K.tin, if you call setState in componentDidUpdate(), would that cause the same data to be fetched again?

For example, [id, data_for_id] are states, and id can be changed by a click counter and data_for_id is fetched from a web API.

Now we click to change Id by setState(), and componentDidUpdate() is executed, which fetches the data_for_id, we do setState for data_for_id, which will trigger another componentDidUpdate().

The first time componentDidUpdate is called, we have prevState.ID = 0 and state.ID=1, so componentDidUpdate is run. The second time we have prevState.ID = 1 and state.ID = 1, and componentDidUpdate can be avoid entirely, which perhaps could also be implemented with shouldComponentUpdate().

Still, this causes TWO rerenders, one for ID change and one for data_for_id change, Ideally, once we detect ID change, data_for_id should be fetched, and we should have [Id, data_for_id] state changed in a single shot, and the rerender happens only once for this change ID click.

So as a general rule, we should not do any setState in componentDidUpdate(), if the change of two or more state components are related, we should perform the changes together in one place and setState in a single shot.

This is just my reasoning. I am not a react guru, so please comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful when it's used. because it's making multiple API calls. Sometimes unlimited calls

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` should not have `setState` inside of it. you should use `componentDidUpdate` specially in manipulating the dom base on `this.state values`. CRUD or updating state values is not good inside of `componentDidUpdate`. Also dont fetching new data inside of `componentDidUpdate` as is can cause multiple http request on server and sometimes can cause laggy specially when the code is not structural or multiple use of `setState`.